# Is syntax highlighting not working for Cardano SE?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Code syntax highlighting doesn't seem to work.  Is this a bug or just a feature that needs to be enabled?

I have tried adding the languages examples from [What is Syntax highlighting...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)

These are either poorly chosen examples or syntax highlighting is not working.  Our users will possibly use lang-haskell or lang-hs

lang-js

```
function greet(person) {
    return "Hello " + person;
}
var user = "Jon Skeet";
alert(greet(user));
```

typescript

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2];  // will highlight if [typescript] tag exists
```

"c" using html format to specify

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("Hello World");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've enabled syntax highlighting here on Cardano both on the main site and on meta. Please let us know if you run into any issues.